# Fast column binding in FME

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

In FME, I would simply like to bind 2 tables columnwise ; they haven't any field in common (but I know that they have the same row order). I have done something with the FeatureMerger (using 1=1 comparison), but it is sooo slow. What would be the fastest way to do the equivalent of R 'cbind' ?

Sorry for the naive question, I am quite newbie in FME

Answer (score 1):

If you use FeatureMerger in a 1=1 comparison, then you're going to see every record in the table merged with every other record. I can imagine that would be quite slow.

I think the better method would be to use a Counter transformer on each table to give them a field in common. Then use the FeatureMerger:

[image]

Make sure each Counter is set to be Local (or Global but with a different Counter name):

[image]

If you don't, then the numbers would accumulate, not give a unique ID per table.

Then in the FeatureMerger, use _count as the attribute to join on.

An alternative would be the FeatureJoiner transformer. You might find that it runs faster than the FeatureMerger.

In general, the other thing about performance testing in FME is to isolate just that one part of the workspace for testing. It's not always clear where or why time is being used. If numbers on connections show features passing singly - rather than in groups of several thousand - then that indicates processing is slower than you would like. Also, turn off feature caching for best performance.

Anyway, lots of little things to look out for, but try the Counter idea first to see if that helps.